# How to Make Virtual OS Utilizes More than One Core?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-workstation

I have a machine ( Windows 7) that has 4 cores. But when I run my Windows XP visualization using VMWare workstation, only one core is available for that visualization.

How to make sure that the virtual OS can also use 4 cores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure the VM to use 4 cores when you first create it.

Comment: first created what? The virtual windows XP OS? Or is there anyway to configure an existing virtual instance?

Comment: The virtual machine itself.